# strange exec file in local bin directory in mac

Tags: macos, malware, bin

There is a strange exec file named  in /usr/local/bin/ in mac.

I've searched but can't find any information about it with google.

Is this a malware or something?any advice will be appreciated.

[its name is just](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWBj1.png)

Comment: It's just a file with a unicode name. I dont think there is anything wrong.

Comment: @minhhh2910 but nothing is like this.

Comment: can you type `ls -lah /usr/local/bin/ ` and post the result instead of that screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, to reassure you, you should do this:
`cp  testfile` 
and then upload the testfile to https://www.virustotal.com/ to analyze. Hope you find the file clean.

Comment: @minhhh2910 It say it's a part of RubyGems called Gym. "cp   file" helped me a lot. and those website would. thank you so much.

Comment: if this really helped you, please consider marking it as a correct answer, thanks